# creating ValueChanged event handler in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm using the DoubleUpDown control from WPFToolkit and I'm trying to create an event handler using ValueChanged.

```
DoubleUpDown dud = new DoubleUpDown();
dud.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged);

private void DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{

}
```

I get the error message

> CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler double' to
>   'System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler object'

Any suggestions on how this can be addressed to ensure no type conflicts? Thanks.

Comment: I'm disappointed not to get the accepted answer, as I posted it 3 minutes before Gabriel's duplicate answer; but it's your choice. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the erros suggests, `ValueChanged` is expecting a `RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>`, so you would have to do this:

```
DoubleUpDown dud = new DoubleUpDown();
dud.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged);

private void DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{

}
```

And inside the handler you will have to cast the `object` to a `double`.

*Note:*

The author left a comment in the source code about that, [here](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Primitives/UpDownBase.cs):

> Due to a bug in Visual Studio, you cannot create event handlers for
>   generic T args in XAML, so I have to use object instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a delve through the [online source code](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Primitives/UpDownBase.cs), and it looks like the declaration of that event is...

```
public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> ValueChanged
```

So your signature needs to match that by making it...

```
private void DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're intending ?

```
dud.ValueChanged += DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged;
private void DoubleUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
     if(e != null && Math.Abs((double)e.NewValue) < 0.000000001d)
     {
        // for example
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may help you

```
 this.dud.ValueChanged += new System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(this.dud_ValueChanged);


private void dud_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
```

Comment: This is a trick. I also have problems like the author, then I use the above statement (the statement is generated by the system), it works. Finally, I tried to rewrite the original and it ran out of errors. it is "visual studio's trick".